# Lumen fails changing headers returning a view

Tags: php, laravel, http-headers, laravel-5, lumen

I'm trying to change some headers in the response returning a view.

I tried this from Lumen's doc ([here](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/responses#other-response-types)):

```
return response()->view('hello', $data)->header('Content-Type', $type);
```

But i get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Laravel\\Lumen\\Http\\ResponseFactory::view() in /project/path/app/Http/Controllers/ExampleController.php on line 108
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Seems like the documentation is wrong? The [ResponseFactory](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.1/src/Http/ResponseFactory.php) doesn't include a `view()` method.

Comment: Maybe you can use the `make()` method. `return response->make(view('hello', $data), 200, ['Content-Type' => $type])`. Or maybe even just  `return response(view('hello', $data), 200, ['Content-Type' => $type])`

Comment: @Jeemusu yeah, I tried with your last code and it works. It seems like a workaround, but it works. If you put it in an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation is a little misleading, as the [ResponseFactory](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.1/src/Http/ResponseFactory.php) doesn't currently implement all the methods outlined in the documentation.

A workaround would be to use the `make()` method:

```
return response->make(view('hello', $data), 200, ['Content-Type' => $type]);
```

or alternatively

```
return response(view('hello', $data), 200, ['Content-Type' => $type]);
```